# Error with Retrofit and moshi while parsing json

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2

I use Kotlin and i want to use retrofit for use imgur's API but I've got this error when my request is send and I received an answer:

> "E/Retrofit: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at path $"

So, this is what i received:

> {"data":["TY5OVQo"],"success":true,"status":200}

From this, I've this data class:

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class ImgurBasic<T>(@Json(name = "data") val data: T,
                         @Json(name = "success") val success: Boolean,
                         @Json(name = "status") val status: Int)
```

I use this interface when i called retrofit:

```
interface Imgur {
    @GET("3/account/{username}/images/ids")
    fun getImages(@Path("username") username: String): Call<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>>
}
```

And how I use retrofit and moshi:

```
val header = StringBuilder("Bearer ").append(AuthSettings.data!!.accessToken!!).toString()
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
client.addInterceptor { chain ->
    val original = chain.request()
    val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        .header("Authorization", header)

    val request = requestBuilder.build()
    chain.proceed(request)
}
val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory()).build()
val service = Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
    .client(client.build())
    .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
    .build()
    .create(Imgur::class.java)
    .getImages(AuthSettings.data!!.accountUsername!!)
    .enqueue(object : Callback<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>>, response: Response<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>>) {
            val body = response.body()
            Log.d("Retrofit", response.message())
            Log.d("Retrofit", if (response.isSuccessful) "true" else "false")

            if (body != null) {
                // Parse data
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.e("Retrofit", t.message) // Error Here
        }
    })
```

In my dataClass i put a template because data could be of different type

Thanks in advance

PS: Sorry for my english ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the answer, I just looked to the wrong place:

```
Call<List<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>>
```

must be:

```
Call<ImgurBasic<List<String>>>
```

I was focus to the content of ImgurBasic.